# can't make post request to hosted node endpoint

Tags: reactjs, node.js, amazon-app-runner

Building a chatbot, using a node server to make the fetch to the AI api, fetching to the node server. Everything works fine locally, but when I hosted the server on apprunner and added the URL to the frontend fetch, I get a 500.

I made sure the hosted server is working by making a GET another route on the same server.

This is the server

```
const { config } = require('dotenv');
config();

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
const dbKey = process.env.DB_KEY;

const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 3000; 

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());  // Use express.json() for JSON parsing

app.post('/fetchData', async (req, res) => {
    const inputValue = req.body.inputValue;

    try {
        const response = await fetch('https://clearai.net/api/database/query/v1', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': apiKey,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                msg: inputValue,
                minLength: 1,
                maxLength: 20,
                stream: false,
                model: 'gpt-4',
                prompt: 'assistant',
                dbKey: dbKey,
            }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        res.json(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

this is the frontend fetch

```
  const handleSendClick = async () => {
    if (inputValue.trim() !== '') {
      const newMessages = [...messages, { type: 'user', text: inputValue }];
      setMessages(newMessages);
      setInputValue('');
      setIsLoading(true);

      try {
        const serverResponse = await fetch('https://i5hp4qmqmk.us-east-1.awsapprunner.com/fetchData', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ inputValue }),
        });

        if (serverResponse.ok) {
          const data = await serverResponse.json();
          const botReply = data.reply || 'No response from the bot.';
          const botMessage = { type: 'bot', text: botReply };
          setMessages([...newMessages, botMessage]);
        } else {
          console.error(
            'Failed to fetch data from the server:',
            serverResponse.statusText
          );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data from the server:', error);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false); // Reset loading state after the fetch
      }
    }
  };
```